# SQL Compare column values

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the data table below:

```
ID  NAME    DATE_FROM       DATE_TO                 PRICE
1   AAA     09.10.2018 16:00    10.10.2018 16:00    4
2   AAA     10.10.2018 16:00    11.10.2018 16:00    5
3   BBB     10.10.2018 16:00    11.10.2018 16:00    6
4   CCC     09.10.2018 16:00    01.01.2019 00:00    7
5   AAA     11.10.2018 16:00    01.01.2019 00:00    7
6   BBB     11.10.2018 16:00    01.01.2019 00:00    5
```

Each item (AAA,BBB,CCC) has a price which is valid between the two given dates. Price changes, if any, will always start and end at 4 PM. I can get current prices with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items 
WHERE DATE_FROM < '11.10.2018 16:00' and DATE_TO >= '11.10.2018 16:00';
```

and prices which are valid after 4 PM with

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items 
WHERE DATE_FROM <= '11.10.2018 16:00' and DATE_TO > '11.10.2018 16:00';
```

I need only the valid prices after 4 PM but i have to distinguish between increased and decreased prices compared to current price. For now i am doing this in java (get current prices and future prices store them in two lists
and make a comparison). Is it possible to get all rows which have a valid price after 4 PM but only if price is incresed with some subselect?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items 
WHERE DATE_FROM <= '11.10.2018 16:00' and DATE_TO > '11.10.2018 16:00' 
and price >(select somehow current price???);
```

to get only

```
5   AAA     11.10.2018 16:00   01.01.2019:00   7
```

since the price for BBB is decreased and CCC not changed.

Comment: What is the datatype of `date_from` and `date_to`?  These should be stored as dates.

Comment: @Gordon those are stored as dates. Wanted only to make it clear that the hour part is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `lag()` to find previous price for each product. Then show only these rows where price increased.

**<sup>[demo](https://rextester.com/OEPQY59540)</sup>**

```
select *
  from (
    select items.*, lag(price) over (partition by name order by date_from) prev_price
      from items )
  where date_from <= to_date('2018-10-11 16:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') 
    and to_date('2018-10-11 16:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') < date_to 
    and prev_price < price
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a double select on the same table and see how that goes.

Something along the lines of this (not tested!):

```
select * from items t1, items t2 
WHERE t1.DATE_FROM < '11.10.2018 16:00' and t1.DATE_TO >= '11.10.2018 16:00'     
and t2.DATE_FROM <= '11.10.2018 16:00' and t2.DATE_TO > '11.10.2018 16:00'
and t1.id = t2.id and t1.price < t2.price;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items 
WHERE DATE_FROM <= '11.10.2018 16:00' and DATE_TO > '11.10.2018 16:00' 
and items.id NOT IN (select id FROM Items WHERE price > Items.price AND name = Items.name);
```

!Not tested

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do a left join with the table `Itens` with itself.

```
SELECT price.id, price.name, price.date_from, price.date_to, price.price, 
       price_before.price price_before
  FROM Items price left join Items price_before on (
    price.name = price_before.name and price.DATE_FROM = price_before.DATE_TO
  )
  WHERE price.DATE_FROM = <x> and price.DATE_TO  = <y>
;
```

This way you join the two rows that are a sequence to each other and have both prices for all rows (the price, and the price before that price).

Then will be easy to compare if the price is higher or lower. If you want only the prices that wore increased you can put in the where clause `price.price > price_before.price`

I could not test this code, because I don't have a database available now. So this can be buggy.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot.